# Azure SQL Data sync

Tags: postgresql, azure, database-replication, azure-postgresql

Use Case:I want to replicate data from my on Premises PostgreSQL database to my PostgreSQl database instance on Azure Cloud.This is not a one time replication/migration.This will be a periodic process.

1)Is Azure SQL Data sync compatible with PostgreSQL database?till now what i learnt from internet is no,but if anyone has any more details please let me know.
2)Suggest a tool which can be used for the above use case.Or any other suggestions to achieve the same.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, Azure Sql Data Sync is just for Sql Server. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database):

> - The Hub Database must be an Azure SQL Database.
> - The member databases can be either databases in Azure SQL Database or in instances of SQL Server.

You are probably better of using [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview). It has a [PostgreSQL connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-postgresql) you can use.
This PostgreSQL connector supports PostgreSQL version 7.4 and above.

Because your data store is located inside an on-premises network, you need to set up a [self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) to connect to it.

You can then create a pipeline with a copy activity that transfers the data from the on-premises db to the cloud db using a [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Azure Database Migration Service to migrate the databases from an on-premises PostgreSQL instance to Azure Database for PostgreSQL. Once created you can run the migration as and when needed. Refer to below articles for step by step migration:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-postgresql-azure-postgresql-online-portal
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/migrate-on-premises-postgresql-databases/
3. https://datamigration.microsoft.com/scenario/postgresql-to-azurepostgresql?step=1